# Loop to get Data in custom NSObject class swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Hi I just wondering how to extract Data out from custom NSObject class my Location NSObject Class below is my NSObject Class (Assume Data already populate from other class)

```
import Foundation


class LocationModel: NSObject {

//properties

var name: String?
var address: String?
var latitude: String?
var longitude: String?


//empty constructor

override init()
{

}

//construct with @name, @address, @latitude, and @longitude parameters

init(name: String, address: String, latitude: String, longitude: String) {

    self.name = name
    self.address = address
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude

}


//prints object's current state

override var description: String {
    return "Name: \(name), Address: \(address), Latitude: \(latitude), Longitude: \(longitude)"

}
```

}

here is my extract data for loop (I have no idea)

```
let MapPoint : LocationModel = LocationModel()
for item in MapPoint {

 let name = MapPoint.name
 let latitude = MapPoint.latitude
 let longitude = MapPoint.longitude

print(name, latitude, longtitude)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, delete the default initializer and declare the properties as constants and non-optionals. The benefit is the compiler will help you to prevent empty data.

```
class LocationModel: NSObject {

//properties

let name, address, latitude, longitude: String

// construct with @name, @address, @latitude, and @longitude parameters

init(name: String, address: String, latitude: String, longitude: String) {

    self.name = name
    self.address = address
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude

}

//prints object's current state

override var description: String {
    return "Name: \(name), Address: \(address), Latitude: \(latitude), Longitude: \(longitude)"

}
```

Now the object to iterate through must be an array of type `[LocationModel]`

```
let mapPoints = [LocationModel(name:"name1", address:"address1", latitude:"latitude1", longitude:"longitude1"),
                 LocationModel(name:"name2", address:"address2", latitude:"latitude2", longitude:"longitude2"),
                 LocationModel(name:"name3", address:"address3", latitude:"latitude3", longitude:"longitude3")]

for item in mapPoints {

   let name = item.name
   let latitude = item.latitude
   let longitude = item.longitude
   print(name, latitude, longitude)

}
```

If the address property could be missing declare the initializer with a default value and treat an empty string as *no value*

```
init(name: String, address: String = "", latitude: String, longitude: String) {...
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I populate data using json data that pass from web service so data I am getting is optional

Comment: A location without `name`, `longitude` and `latitude` makes no much sense in real life. ;-) And even if the data comes from a web database it's most likely that always all fields are sent.